# How to keep fixed gaps while changing the page width?

Tags: html, css

Please take a look at my code, click the 'Run' button to see the result:

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG1HLL1GNU7B

```css
.outsideDiv {
  background-color: green;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}
.insideDiv {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.shortItem {
  background-color: white;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outsideDiv">
  <div class="insideDiv">
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is showing here:

[image]

But I just unable to make it work. I want that when the user change the page width the gaps between the white items will stay fixed, `20px`, and also that the gap between the most left and the most right items and the yellow div's border will be exactly `20px`.

How can I do that?

(You can change my code, save it using the upper menu, and then give here a link to the fixed code)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `display: flex` saves some of the calculations in regards to positioning the `.innerDiv` and its children:

```css
.outsideDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: green;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.insideDiv {
  background-color: yellow;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 90%;
}
.shortItem {
  background-color: white;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 17px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outsideDiv">
  <div class="insideDiv">
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
    <div class="shortItem"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Take a look in full page mode to get the design in your image.

Comment: Sorry but this code still not giving me the result that I was looking for... check this image: https://ibb.co/f0H45v

Comment: You can't specify the container's width as a percentage and the children's width as a static value and get a consistent display with those gap requirements.

Answer (score 0):

is that what you looking for . Let me know ... if its ok or not ?
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG1J3XI6KHHM

Comment: check this  [link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG2LR9ACQNX5)

Comment: Minar, did you try to run your code and check the result? can't you see that when you change the page width (the display section) the gap on the right side all the time changing and not keeping fixed size of 20 pixels?

Comment: then i think it will not achievable .... because of fixed height and width of shortItem class .

Comment: Sorry but this are the requirements... the shortItems will later hold some bitmaps and images that their size must be fixed ...

Answer (score 0):

you need to just change the float property which is set to right. Change it to the left and
see the result it would be same as you expected
[Check This](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FG1HLL1GNU7B)